# compare two list of xmls in python

Tags: python, xml

I have two lists of xml, expected and actual.
for each expected in expected list i want to compare it with each actual and find out if is matching with any xml in actual list.

each mesg looks like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
\n
<stlTxn>
    <InstrumnetID>796</InstrumnetID>
    <Version>0</Version>
    <ProductType>OSTK</ProductType>
    <Strike>190.0</Strike>
    <AccountID>3236</AccountID>
    <Symbol>ALV</Symbol>
    <SettlAmount>1520000.0</SettlAmount>
    <ClearingBusinessDate>2013-12-18</ClearingBusinessDate>
    <CptySettlAccount>8501</CptySettlAccount>
    <ProductISIN>DE00004005</ProductISIN>
    <ProductCurrency>EUR</ProductCurrency>
    <SettlCurrency>EUR</SettlCurrency>
    <AccrIntAmount>0.0</AccrIntAmount>
    <SettlQuantity>8000.0</SettlQuantity>
    <AccountSponsor>CBKFR</AccountSponsor>
    <CallPut>0</CallPut>
    <DelvSettlPrice>190.0</DelvSettlPrice>
    <AccountName>EXY</AccountName>
    <CashSettlAmount>0.0</CashSettlAmount>
    <Maturity>201312</Maturity>
    <Side>0</Side>
    <ClearingHouse>ECAG</ClearingHouse>
    <AccrIntDays>0</AccrIntDays>
    <DeliveryType>DELIVERY_AT_SETTLEMENT_AMOUNT</DeliveryType>
    <ProductName>OPT ON ALLIANZ AG HOLDIN</ProductName>
    <ProductSymbol>ALV</ProductSymbol>
    <Currency>EUR</Currency>
    <AccountOwner>CBKFR</AccountOwner>
    <ValueDate>2013-12-20</ValueDate>
    <ProductID>jigfj</ProductID>
</stlTxn>
```

**I tried to use beautiful soup package:**

```
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 
    expected_parsed = BeautifulSoup(expected)
    actual_parsed = BeautifulSoup(actual)
    if expected_parsed.text != actual_parsed.text:
       print "failed"
```

Comment: By comparing you mean an exact match on list level or item level?

Comment: I want to compare value of each element for e.g instrumentid,version etc.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is trickier than it might seem at first as the chronology of elements can change, as well as the hierarchy structure. You only really want to be comparing similar XML documents. I suggest you look at the lxml module, and sequentially parse the first XML and for each tag check to see if the second A: has the same tag B: has the same tag value and C: has the same attributes.

If you are able to assume that the two XML documents will always have the same elements and the same hierarchy structure then you might find the following interesting...

```
from lxml import etree
import os

def compareXMLs( xmlFilePath1, xmlFilePath2 ):
  if not os.path.isfile( xmlFilePath1 ):
    raise Exception( "Invalid file path: \'" + str(xmlFilePath1) + "\'" )
  if not os.path.isfile( xmlFilePath1 ):
    raise Exception( "Invalid file path: \'" + str(xmlFilePath2) + "\'" )

  xmlDoc1 = etree.parse( xmlFilePath1 )
  xmlDoc2 = etree.parse( xmlFilePath2 )

  if set( xmlDoc1.getroot().itertext() ) == set( xmlDoc2.getroot().itertext() ):
    return True
  return False
```

This is my second ever stack overflow post so forgive me if this is a rubbish answer.
Oh, I've never tried it but I think the etree.parse() method can also take a HTTP/FTP URL.
Good luck!